# Php closure in a class method call

Tags: php, closures

Lets say I have two classes Car and Owner

owner.php =>

```
class Owner {
  public $name;

  public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
}
```

and respectively the car.php =>

```
class Car {
  public $owner;

  public function setOwner(Owner $owner) {
    $this->owner = $owner;
  }
}
```

To set and call methods I normally use this approach =>

```
$owner = new Owner;
$owner->setName('sam');


$car = new Car;
$car->setOwner($owner);
```

But what if I want it to do using Closure like below, how do I change the setOwner method accordingly?

```
$car = new Car;
$car->setOwner(function(Owner $owner) {

  $owner->setName('sam');
});
```

What I want to do is something similar to Laravel `where`

```
User::where('car_id', $carId)

or 


User::where(function($query) {

  //code here 
})
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work? How does `Car` know which `Owner` to set the name of?

Comment: Why would a car set its owner's name, anyway?

Comment: `Car::setOwner()` needs to call the closure with an `Owner` argument. Where would that come from, if you're not using `setOwner()` to specify which owner owns it?

Comment: Maybe what you want is two methods: `setOwner` and `setOwnersName`. The second method would use `$this->owner`.

Comment: I just created this as in example, I wanted to know how to set value  in Closure and get that object in the method.

Comment: "But what if I want it to do using Closure like below" <- why exactly would you want that? What you're doing right now is perfectly fine, easy to read and maintainable. No need for extra complexity.

Comment: What's the point of using a closure here? You get no benefit.

Comment: @Jeto That is true, but it's for me to learn and experiment on

Comment: @Sherif oooh! that is harsh, lol

Comment: I wanted to make something like Laravel where(Closure)

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but this question makes no sense. It's lost on me what you're asking right now. It sounds to me like you're basically asking how do Closures work and can someone give me a practical example of using one. I'm afraid these aren't the types of questions meant for StackOverflow. Everyone would tell you to read the manual. I'm sorry if that's harsh, but that's reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Car::setOwner()` needs to call its argument with an `Owner` object.

```
class Car {

  public function setOwner(Callable $ownerSetter) {
    $o = new Owner;
    $ownerSetter($o);
  }
}
```

But this is a strange way to use a closure. A better example might be:

```
class Car {
  private $owner;

  public function setOwner($owner) {
    $this->owner = $owner;
  }

  public function doSomethingToOwner(Callable $something) {
    $something($this->owner);
  }
}

$car->setOwner($owner);
$car->doSomethingToOwner(function($owner) {
  echo $owner->name;
});
```

Comment: Hard coupling the car and its owner instance seems like a bad idea. I know you're answering the question exactly as it was asked, but pointing out that it's not exactly recommended might be relevant. You could alternatively have [this](https://3v4l.org/RLBo4) (without coupling the two), but again, this doesn't provide any benefit compared to what OP had initially.

Comment: I tried to get more details in the comments, but he said this is just a simple example. He just wants to see how the data flows.

Comment: I've added a more useful way to use closures.

Comment: @Barmar What my Idea was to combine the functionality setOwner and doSomethingToOwner into one. I guess i will just check if its a callable and call it a day.

Comment: @menaka But what do you want to set the owner to? You need to provide the new owner as a parameter to the method.

Comment: In your Laravel example, it's using the data that was previously stored in the `User` object, and then performing some operations on it. It's not combining two operations in one. It's similar to my second example.